# Creating a Table with 3D Arrays with Ng-Repeat Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table to display the data inside of it as shown in the picture below. The best way i can imagine to create a 3D array to show it with ng-repeat, hence there is no question like mine to display it so that I could think of it's impossible with it.

[image]

I have tried but nothing have precise yet even i could do something similar with a 2D array in the snippet below.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.grid = [
    [
      ["June"],
      ["July"],
      ["August"],
      ["September"]
    ],
    [
      ["0,1"],
      ["1,1"],
      ["4,5"],
      ["2,1"]
    ]
    [
      ["3,2"],
      ["1,0"],
      ["6,3"],
      ["2,9"]
    ]
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Install</th>
          <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Uninstall</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th>AppName1</th>
          <th>AppName2</th>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
          <th>AppName1</th>
          <th>AppName2</th>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="y in grid">
          <td ng-repeat="x in y">{{x}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="x in y">{{x[0]}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

or there is a [plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/h2Qlem3zZ2lubNmbWJ7M?p=preview) which I still play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking the question and not getting the answer for 'displaying the data on 3D arrays using ng-repeat directive', soon I figured out the solution below.

First I discovered that the code block below displays the very first element of 3D array,

```
<tbody ng-repeat="y in grid">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in y">
      <td>{{x[0]}}</td>
```

and then I configured my array to fit in the new situation like below, that's all;

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.grid = [
    [
      ["June", "0", "1", "1", "3", "2", "5"],
      ["July", "1", "1", "2", "1", "0", "1"],
      ["August", "4", "5", "9", "6", "3", "9"],
      ["September", "2", "1", "3", "2", "9", "11"]
    ]
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Install</th>
          <th class="text-center" colspan="3">Uninstall</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <th>AppName1</th>
          <th>AppName2</th>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
          <th>AppName1</th>
          <th>AppName2</th>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="y in grid">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in y">
          <td ng-repeat="z in x">{{z}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```